# List being shortened when writing it to a txt file

Tags: list, file, python-3.x

I am using Python 3.

I have done some coding to get two lists, timlist and acclist, and zipped them into a tuple. I now want to write each element of the tuple in a column in a text file.

```
f = open("file.txt", "w")
for f1, f2 in zip(timlist, acclist):
print(f1, "\t", f2, "\n", file=f)    
f.close
```

When I run this, I get only part of the lists but if I run it as

```
f = open("file.txt", "w")
for f1, f2 in zip(timlist, acclist):
print(f1, "\t", f2, "\n")
f.close
```

I get the full thing I want. Why is my list being shortened when writing it to a txt file?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with the code. It works fine for me with Python 3.4.1. Any reason you're not just writing it to the file directly, instead of using the file param of the print function?

Comment: That's so strange. Mine will not write everything to the file in the first code.How would I write to the file directly? I'm still pretty new to python so only really know one way of doing each thing

Comment: I can't answer the question 'why doesn't it work?', since it works for me. But I did post an answer that may help you. Good luck.

Comment: I found that the issue was having written f.close instead of f.close()

Comment: When I retyped your example, I added the parentheses without thinking. So it worked for me. Should have done copy/paste. But see my answer for a better way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you discovered, the file is not being closed because you left the parentheses off: should be `f.close()` instead of `f.close`. But I thought I would also post an answer that shows how you might do this in a bit more idiomatic Python, where the call to `f.close()` is done for you, even if an error occurs in your loop:

```
timlist = [1,2,3,4]
acclist = [9,8,7,6]

with open('file.txt', 'w') as f: # use a context for the file, that way it gets close for you automatically when the context ends
    for f1, f2 in zip(timlist, acclist):
        f.write('{}\t{}\n'.format(f1, f2)) # use the format method of the string object to create your string and write it directly to the file
```

Good luck learning Python!

Comment: I found that the issue was having written f.close instead of f.close()
I don't know why it would stop writing the file because of that.
Thank you for the proper python to write to a file